# Codeigniter url gets appended every click

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a problem with CI whenever i click a button in a form which has an action of image/upload or a hyperlink with the same link it gets appended whenever i click it the second time. say for example my home is localhost/admin and i click a button or a link which has image/upload.. so the url will now beh localhost/admin/image/upload but when i click the same button the second time the url will now beh calhost/admin/image/image/upload wchich well then cause a 404 error which ofcourse is the error given that the page is not found by just seeing that url. it gets appended every time i click the button or the link.

Anyone of you knows this please do share!

UPDATES: 
BTW just a headsup for all those people who didn't know or who encountered this problem.. USE anchor or any helper in CI becuase if you manually put links in href or actions on form tag without putting the base_url.. your URL will be messed up.. helpers do append base_url. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the Codeigniter docs and the URL Helper.  That should help out.

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html

I know for anchors you would just do:

```
echo anchor('image/upload', 'Upload');
```

This will append the url to the base url and you don't have to worry about changing anything or any 404 errors.

Comment: how about in form actions?

Comment: Check out the Form Helper: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html

Comment: Well, if `admin` is the controller, you have to do `admin/image/upload`.  If `admin` is the base URL, then you need to change your base_url like everyone says.

Comment: by the way i thought anchor will return a url whicn contains the base url plus the first params? when i checked out the anchor using firebug its only /mage/upload?

Comment: i've alrady changed it on my config.php

Answer (score 2):

just put **http://** at infront of your link.

or otherwise

change your config file:

```
$config['base_url'] =  'http://www.yourhost.com/home';
```

Answer (score 0):

try to link the url as `'/path-to-url'`. notice `'/'` before url.

```
<a href="/image/upload"> Link </a>
```

currently you might be doing like below

```
<a href="image/upload"> Link </a>
```

Also try changing

```
$config['base_url'] =  'http://localhost/home/';
```

Comment: try added solution in answer

Comment: by the way when i tried the first one it does something like this.. given the http thing on the first part.. localhost/image/upload.. admin is gone